# VS2010: Multiple solutions, one shared C# project file/GUID

Tags: visual-studio-2010, guid, projects-and-solutions

We have several teams which share and collaboratively develop a certain SharedProject.csproj, which is a shared component across many products. They do so as each develops its own product (each product has its own solution file).

Each team references SharedProject.csproj in their respective solution file. Neither team has changed anything about that project, but source control keeps reporting the file as changed.

It turns out that each VS2010 solution file references that project, with a *solution-specific GUID for that project*. Even though the project is the same, each solution references it with a unique GUID.

This solution-specific GUID gets injected into the SharedProject.csproj file each time the next team opens their solution.

How can we prevent VS2010 from changing/editing this SharedProject.csproj file unexpectedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit each solution file to reference SharedProject.csproj by the same GUID.

Comment: This is all I've thought of so far.  I'm hoping there's a better answer than this (which doesn't require editing every product's solution file).

Comment: It would appear that this is no longer an issue? I just added a project from one solution to also be included in a second one, and nothing changed in the csproj file.

Comment: @MiikaL. using which version of VS?

Comment: VS2010. Had a solution, which included several projects. One of these projects was also added to a second solution, and it didn't change any IDs, or require any manual editing. Simply Add Project. Both solutions still open and compile correctly.